# mysql - what does a : before a value in sql mean?

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I'm a noob with sql and trying to figure my way through zencart. There's a bit in the code where it prepares a SELECT statement and amongst that there is the following line:

```
AND   cd.language_id = :languagesID
```

I can't figure out what the `:` does. I thought maybe it refers to a $variable like $languagesID but I can't find that variable anywhere either.

What does the `:` do? Google left me none the wiser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for prepared SQL statements. It's replaced later on with an actual value. Google "Prepared SQL"